# Edit org-agenda Files

Tags: org-agenda, list

Is there a way to edit the files which are included in org-agenda?

I have a pretty long list and want to just tidy up a bit.

I know I have the variable stored in init.el, but it's just one long line of list elements.

Can I somehow format this list, so that each elements is on a separate line? That would help editing the list;)

Comment: Read the doc string of the variable `org-agenda-files`: there are various formats that you can use. Read also the doc string of the *function* `org-agenda-files` for how Org mode calculates the list of files that will contribute to the agenda.

Answer (score 2):

Help about the variable `org-agenda-files`:

> If the value of the variable is not a list but a single file name, then
> the list of agenda files is actually stored and maintained in that file,
> one agenda file per line.

Comment: This is one possibility: there are others as explained in the doc string of the variable `org-agenda-files`.